# pppoe-server log file

Tags: linux, debian, pppoe

I have installed successfully the roar-penguin pppoe-server and trying to use it without success, what I don't understand is that, when I put in my `/etc/ppp/pppoe-server-options`

```
debug
logfile /var/log/pppoe-server-log
```

But that file is not created and I don't understand what happens. It is really hard for me find a solution. Do you know how can I enable the debugging ?

My problem is that I catch every time (Wireshark sniffing) the

```
RP-PPPoE: Child pppd process terminated
```

In the PADT message, any help ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

From your question not being formatted, verify that **debug** and **logfile** in */var/log/pppoe-server-log* are on separate lines in your configuration file. Also, ensure that you've restarted the service to utilize the new configuration. If the service is not running as root, be sure that the user it runs as has ownership over the logfile to write to it. If it is running as root, ensure the file exists and that it's writable.

If it doesn't exist, just run:

```
# touch /var/log/pppoe-server-log
# chmod 0774 /var/log/pppoe-server-log
```

I would think this should be done automatically, but you may as well do so just to ensure it's created properly and you can verify ownership/permissions as needed.

Comment: "If it is running as root, ensure the file exists and that it's writable", really ? If I am root I have to be worried about the file existence ?

Comment: I can't validate that the software is doing what it should, so I would recommend just doing it yourself and removing a variable regarding the log file. The more you can control, the less you have to troubleshoot.